# insert/update data to 3 tables on one query joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla

I had a problem need to optimize following 3 query in one. can I create a function?

```
$query = "UPDATE #__sbc SET payment_reference ='".$payref."', payment_status = '".$state."' WHERE reference ='".$ref."'";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $db->query();
                //update allforms table
$query = "UPDATE #__allforms SET payment_reference ='".$payref."', payment_status = '".$state."' WHERE reference ='".$ref."'";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $db->query();
$query = "UPDATE #__printxml SET payment_reference ='".$payref."', payment_status = '".$state."' WHERE reference ='".$ref."'";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $db->query();
```

Comment: Creating a function will only optimize one round trip to the database instead off three round trips you won't get much results out off that. A better optimize would be indexing the column reference of all tabels if not indexed

Comment: how about change to 1 query? How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine queries by adding semi column (;) to the end of the query. For example:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET `field1`=2 WHERE `id`=5;UPDATE TABLE1 SET `field1`=3 WHERE `id`=6;
```

The thing is, combining queries is unlikely to provide any (even slightly) noticeable performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

I don't clearly understand what you mean here by optimizing, sorry if I misunderstood but maybe you meant something like this? Explain what do you mean by optimizing 3 queries in one

```
$params=array("sbc","allforms","printxml");

foreach ($params as $param){

    $query = "UPDATE #__".$param." SET payment_reference ='".$payref."', payment_status = '".$state."' WHERE reference ='".$ref."'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();

}
```